# Salvar execução python como arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou criando uma calculadora de ganhos líquidos para motorista de Uber, ai eu gostaria de salvar os "input" como um arquivo de texto, Word ou Excel. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

````
bruto = float(input('\033[0mQual o seu ganho bruto total? (APENAS NÚMEROS) '))

passageiro = int(input('Quantos passageiro você pegou? (APENAS NÚMEROS) '))

km = float(input('Quantos Kilometros você andou? '))

autonomia = float(input('Qual tem sido a autonomia do carro? '))

valorlitro = float(input('Qual o valor da gasolina que tem comprado? '))

gastogas = (passageiro / km) * (autonomia / valorlitro)

porcentagem = int(input('Qual a porcentagem cobrada pela Uber? (APENAS NÚMEROS) '))

por = (bruto / 100) * porcentagem

total = (bruto - gastogas) - por

print('\033[36mRetirando todas as cobranças o seu lucro total foi de R${}'.format(total))
```
````

Comment: pesquise função open

Comment: Você quer salvar os textos que aparecem no input (por exemplo, "Qual o seu ganho bruto total?") ou as respostas que serão lidas para responder aos inputs?

Comment: Leila eu quero salvar as respostas lidas no input, para poder ter algo como um banco de dados mensais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para armazenar todos os dados obtidos, você pode salvá-los em um arquivo JSON — utilizando o pacote [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) da biblioteca padrão do Python.

Arquivos JSON armazenam os dados em forma de um dicionário. Logo, você deverá inicialmente separar cada item dentro de um `dict`, da seguinte forma:

```
dados = {
    "bruto": bruto, "passageiro": passageiro, "km": km, "autonomia": autonomia, 
    "valorlitro": valorlitro, "gastogas": gastogas, "porcentagem": porcentagem
}
```

Após isso, transforme o objeto em uma string JSON — utilizando a função `json.dumps` — e salve-a em um arquivo com a extensão `.json`, como no código abaixo:

```
import json

with open("banco de dados.json", "w") as file:
    string_json = json.dumps(dados)
    file.write(string_json)
```

No seu caso, como você disse que os dados serão armazenados mensalmente, crie uma lista para cada chave. Dessa forma, você poderá sempre adicionar novos dados.

O código completo para criar o "banco de dados" ficaria assim:

```
import json

dados = {
    "bruto": [bruto,],
    "passageiro": [passageiro,],
    "km": [km,],
    "autonomia": [autonomia,], 
    "valorlitro": [valorlitro,],
    "gastogas": [gastogas,],
    "porcentagem": [porcentagem,]
}


with open("database.json", "w") as file:
    string_json = json.dumps(dados)
    file.write(string_json)
```

Já para adicionar novos dados ao banco de dados, basta ler o arquivo JSON — verifique primeiro se ele existe — e utilizar a função `json.loads` para obter um objeto `dict` da string.

Após isso, adicione à lista os novos valores, através do método `append` e salve os dados novamente, seguindo as etapas acima. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
with open("database.json") as file:
    string_json = file.read()
    dados = json.loads(string_json)

dados["bruto"].append(bruto)
dados["passageiro"].append(passageiro)

# ...
```

Comment: MUITO obrigado mesmo

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu consigo escolher em qual pasta do meu pc será salvo esse arquivo?

Comment: Sim. Basta colocar o diretório antes do nome do arquivo: `open("<diretório>/database.json", "w")`.

Comment: Nossa cara salvou minha vida, muito obrigado